# Why are simple for loop expressions restricted to integer ranges?

Tags: for-loop, f#, inline, control-flow, imperative-programming

According to the F# spec (see [§6.5.7](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc335818859)), simple for loops are bounded by integer (`int` aka `int32` aka `System.Int32`) limits `start` and `stop`, e.g.

```
for i = start to stop do
    // do sth.
```

I wonder why the iteration bounds for this type of for loop are required to be `int32`. Why not allow `uint32`? `int64`? `bigint`?

I'm aware that sequence iteration expressions (`for ... in ...`) can iterate over arbitrary sequences; that however requires allocating an iterator and calling `MoveNext` and `Current` and what not and can thus be considerably less efficient than a plain loop could be (increment counter, compare, conditonal jump). To avoid that, you are stuck with using `while` and a manually incrementing loop counters...

Strangely enough, F# *does* allow non-`int32` loop bounds, if the `for` expression is wrapped in a sequence expression, e.g.

```
seq { for i = 0I to 10I do
        printfn "%A" i }
```

So, I guess the question is: Is there a particular reason for only allowing `int32` for loops? And why does this restriction not apply to `for` loops wrapped in `seq` expressions?

Comment: In general, the .NET framework uses `int` as a general-purpose integer, including its use in all sorts of numerical indexing scenarios.  Example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.indexof(v=vs.71).aspx.  Counter-example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.position.aspx, which uses a long.

Comment: F# encourages functional programming and therefore stops short of full imperative support (e.g., the lack of `break`/`return`). Within a computation expression `for` is desugared to a method call, which isn't inherently imperative like a loop, and therefore doesn't have the same limits. I can understand the mystery though. +1

Comment: @Daniel +1 "Within a computation expression for is desugared to a method call". I see; actually the code generated for `seq { for .. to .. do .. }` and `seq { for .. in .. do }` is largely identical, both are transformed to a `GeneratedSequenceBase<_>` enumerator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure why F# does not allow `int64` ranges. It sounds like a useful feature... (but I can understand that `int` is the standard type for this in C# and perhaps F# tries to follow this pattern).

As for the workarounds, it is worth adding that you can also write `inline` higher-order function:

```
let inline longFor low high f = 
  let rec loop n =
    if n < high then f n; loop (n + 1L)
  loop low
```

...and then you can express `for` loops over `int64` ranges in a fairly succinct way:

```
longFor 1L 100L (fun n -> 
  <whatever> )
```

I did a couple of experiments and it seems that the F# compiler is able to optimize this fairly decently (the lambda function is inlined and the tail-recursive `loop` function is turned into a `while` loop). I do not think this is *guaranteed* so you may need to check this by hand in high-performance code, but it seems to work fine for simpler examples.

There is only one disadvantage - you won't be able to use local mutable variables (`let mutable`) because these cannot be captured by a lambda function. So there may be additional cost with indirect `ref` cells (but I'm not sure how big problem this is).

Comment: +1 I also recently experimented with how the F# compilers handles inlined higher-order functions and I was quite surprised (and pleased) to see that it even inlines lambdas at the call site, at least as of F# 3.0. I now use an approach very similar to your suggestion, but with an imperative while loop instead of tail-recursion (so I can use a plain mutable instead of a ref cell). Seems to work fine so far.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the for-loop, there's a very simple work-around using the [for...in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233227.aspx) loop with a [sequence range operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233209.aspx):

```
for i in 0I .. 10I do
    printfn "%A" i
```

The range operator will accept any integer of any size as long as both types match. For example, the following will *not* compile:

```
for i in 0 .. 10I do
    printfn "%A" i
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm aware of that; read the second paragraph of my question.

Comment: Oops... missed that. Was coming from [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21292082/211627)...

Answer (score 0):

Another possible workaround:

[1L..100L] |> List.iter (fun i -> printfn "%i" i)